# Deploying on Arbitrum using Infura endpoint

Tags: web3js, infura, rinkeby, arbitrum

I am trying to deploy a contract on Arbitrum testnet using Infura as web3 provider.

In my profile with Infura I added Arbitrum as a network.

Then I do

const url ='https://arbitrum-rinkeby.infura.io/v3/my_project_id'

const web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url);

However, when trying to deploy , I am getting error

Error: Chain with name arbitrum-rinkeby not supported

The same error happens if I just use "arbitrum" instead of arbitrum-rinkeby.

What is going on?

EDIT: here is the code I use for deployment

`web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr, (err,txCount) => {
console.log("txCount=",txCount);
const txObject = {
nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1500000),
gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(100000000),
data: data.encodeABI()
}
const tx = new Tx(txObject,{chain:'arbitrum-rinkeby', hardfork: 'petersburg'});
tx.sign(key);
const serializeTx = tx.serialize();
const raw = '0x'+serializeTx.toString('hex');
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw).on('receipt', console.log);
})`

Comment: Hi! it would be good if you could post the code that you are trying to use so that we can have a better picture! Anyway I'll add some first impressions in the answers section =)

Answer (score 1):

Developer advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

At first glance, it looks like the code you are using to create the provider instance doesn't work, try this:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3"); 
const node_url = "NODE_URL"; 
const web3 = new Web3(node_url);
```

I was able to retrieve data without problems using this format.

Chainstack has a section in the docs dedicated to the [Arbitrum API](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/arbitrum/arbitrum-api-reference#start-building-on-arbitrum-using-the-json-rpc-arbitrum-api), you can use it to reference code examples!

The second point is that Rinkeby is considered deprecated and will shut down soon; it's even still on proof of work!

> Check out this [article about the merge](https://chainstack.com/merge-a-step-by-step-guide-for-developers/) where you can find which testnets are deprecated!

So my suggestion is to switch to the `Arbitrum Goerli testnet`. Then, if you have issues with your endpoint, you can try Chainstack for free!

- [Join the Arbitrum network on Chainstack](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/join-a-public-network#join-an-arbitrum-network) in case you decide to test a different endoint.